# Generating client code with NSwag - problem with nested classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

So I have ASP.NET Core webservice which uses MediatR to pass request from controllers to appropriate handlers. So in turn I have nested classes:

```
public class SomeCommand
{
    public class Request : IRequest<Response> {}

    public class Response {}

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Request, Response> {}
}
```

So, in turn, `Request` and `Response` are my DTOs.

Now I am trying to generate client package with NSwag, which ignores external classes (`SomeCommand`) and produces DTOs with names `Request`, `Request1`, etc., same for `Response`.

I use NSwag.MSBuild package to automatically generate code when building the API.

Ideally, I would like to get generated names as `SomeCommand_Request` or `SomeCommandRequest`.

I tried `"AllowReferencesWithProperties": true` in nswag.json configuration file, but it did not work.

Other than that, I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded source code for every nuget package involved in NSwag and analyzed down to the root.

If I am not mistaken, at the very core, only class name is taken into account, so there does not exist any option to achieve what I am trying to do.

So answer is: this is not possible and one should use another tool if possible or create own :(

It seems like someone tried to add similair functionality, but pull request is stuck since 2 years now:

[AppendSchema method will receive the type information](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/pull/1001)

[More Flexible Type Name Generation](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/pull/2218/files)

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer a clean architecture and use MediatR. In my case, I needed to generate DTOs for my Angular client application. Since in the controllers, we only explicitly see the Request, NSwag generated it, while the Response remained unknown to OpenAPI.

For example, an API for logging into an account:

```
[HttpPost("access/login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> LogInToAccount(LogInToAccountQueryRequest request)
{
    return Ok(await _sender.Send(new LogInToAccountQuery(request)));
}
```

Here, we explicitly see the Request: LogInToAccountQueryRequest, and OpenAPI does too. However, the Response remains unknown because the request is passed to MediatR.

For me, the obvious solution was to explicitly specify what the controller should return:

```
[HttpPost("access/login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<LogInToAccountQueryView>> LogInToAccount(LogInToAccountQueryRequest request)
{
    return Ok(await _sender.Send(new LogInToAccountQuery(request)));
}
```

It is crucial not to get confused in the naming of DTO classes. The approach used in the example is also convenient, and I use it in my projects as well. It works well if you initially organize everything neatly into directories and name classes consistently. I haven't encountered issues with a large number of controllers, except for the sheer number of classes, which is a nuance of a clean architecture.